# ZeroMQ sending many to one

Tags: c++, sockets, process, zeromq

I have implemented a zmq library using push / pull on windows.  There is a server and up to 64 clients running over loopback.   Each client can send and receive to the server.  There is a thread that waits for each client to connect on a pull zmq socket.  Clients can go away at any time.

The server is expected to go down at times and when it comes back up the clients need to reconnect to it.

The problem is that when nothing is connected I have 64 receive threads waiting for a connection.  This shows up as a lot of connections in tcpview and my colleagues inform me that this is appearing like a performance/d-dos sort of attack.

So in order to get around that issue I'd like the clients to send some sort of heart beat to the server "hey I'm here" on one socket.  However I can't see how to do that with zmq.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Poller class? Also, are you using one context for all sockets? If using multiple contexts you will have extra threads..

Comment: Do you mean you have 64 sockets on the server, all waiting for their clients to connect?

Comment: Yes that's what the general idea is.  What's the best zmq pattern for this?  It also must allow me to detect disconnections and reconnections which I am currently doing with heartbeats.

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic design of having 64 threads on the server waiting for external connections is flawed. Why not have a single 'master' thread binding the socket, which the external clients would connect to?

Internal to the server, you could still have 64 worker threads. Work would be distributed to the worker threads by the master thread. The communication between the master and the worker threads would be using zmq messages over the inproc transport.

What I have described are simple fan-in and fan-out patterns which are covered in the zmq guide. If you adopt this, most of the zmq code in the clients and workers would remain unchanged. You would have to write code for the master thread, but the zproxy class of CZMQ may work well for you (if you're using CZMQ).

So my advice is to get the basic design right before trying to add heartbeats. [Actually, I'm not sure how heartbeats would help your current problem.]

Comment: It's an interesting idea to explore.  Note the heartbeats are necessary because zmq doesn't provide information about reconnection or disconnection.  The client is sending so the server only knows that that client is awake if it receives a heartbeat.  There is app level changes that need to change when the app disconnects or reconnects.

Comment: OK. I would certainly look at the fan-in / fan-out design.

Comment: Adding heartbeats is fairly straightforward. There are examples in the zmq guide, the Paranoid Pirate pattern is one of them.